# replace fragment on button click of viewholder

Tags: android, android-viewholder

I wanna replace fragment on button click in viewholder.

viewholder

```
static class ViewHolder {
Button button;
TextView title;
}
```

Adapter class of FragmentA that consists listview

```
viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA();
            fragmentA.nextFragment();
        }
    });
```

FragmentA

```
public void nextFragment(){
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new FragmentB()).commit();
}
```

giving nullpointerexception when replacing fragment

logcat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.testapp.fragment.FragmentA.nextFragment(FragmentA.java:75)
            at com.example.testapp.adapter.FragmentAListAdapter$1.onClick(FragmentAListAdapter.java:54)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17620)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5370)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: in adapter argument pass the instance of the Fragment Manager and use it for replace fragment

Comment: thanks.. this worked but but how to add it to back stack?? i tried adding it to backstack but on backpress, screen got blank

Answer (score 1):

Try to make your nextfragment function in your activity. 
Like this :-

```
public static void nextfragment(FragmentManager activity,Fragment fragment) {
        if (fragment == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            activity.popBackStack();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

and use it when ever you need from using getactivity instance.

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).nextfragment();
```